# css and javascript in just one page (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm starting with Rails 4 and I have a couple of questions about assets.
How can I specify that a CSS just must be included in some view?
I have the same question about a JS file. I have added a JS file to app/assets/javascripts/viewname.js
however it is included in every page. I would like it to be seen just in viewname view.

Help me please!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Save the file as `/vendor/assets/javascripts/viewname.js` and include it in your view with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'viewname' %>
```

#### To include the JS file in the HTML header

Use `content_for` in a view file to collect content that will be rendered later.

```
<% content_for :head %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'viewname' %>
<% end %>
```

Call `yield` in the layout template to render the collected content:

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
```

To automatically include a javascript file named after the current controller, you could also put this in your layout template file:

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "#{params[:controller]}_#{params[:action]}" # variant with action name %>
</head>
```

But that will give 404 errors for a controllers/actions without a javascript file.

Comment: this solution involves that the <script> tag will be outside <head> tag. Isn't there any way to do this automatically. I mean, rails knows the name of the view rendered, so rails should look for any viewname.js and viewname.css inside assets folder

Comment: Updated answer with part about including in `<head>`.

Comment: it should be <% content_for : head do %>